# Wreq: Stop 404s throwing exceptions

Tags: haskell

I am trying to test broken links but, when I use Wreq's `get` method and run into a 404, I get an exception (see bottom) rather than a statusCode to handle. Only 200s seem to be returned.

I tried to follow the error-handling code in the [tutorial](http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/tutorial.html#error-handling) but I can't find a way to return the same type as `get u`. Moreover, this seems to be more complexity than I need in this instance.

How can I simply prevent the exception and just return the responseStatus as is

```
verifySeatme :: Maybe URL -> IO UrlStatus
verifySeatme url = do
    case url of
        Nothing -> return None
        Just "" -> return None
        Just u -> do
            seatmeResp <- get u --`E.catch` handler
            -- r ^? responseBody . key "url"
            -- could also check for redirect to errorPage.aspx
            if seatmeResp ^. W.responseStatus . statusCode == 200
            then return (Working u)
            else return Broken
    where
        handler e@(StatusCodeException s respHeaders _) =
            do
                return respHeaders
```

Here is the exception thrown, and you can see it has the stateCode i want

```
*Main> re <- get "https://www.seatme.nl/restaurant/1371/Londen.htm"
*** Exception: StatusCodeException (Status {statusCode = 404, statusMessage = "Not Found"}) [("Cache-Control","private"),....
```

Yuras suggested using options, but I have been unable to work from the example using `params` to one using `checkStatus :: Lens' Options (Maybe StatusChecker)`:

```
getData :: IO Restos
getData = do
    let opts = defaults & customStatusHandler
    jdata <- asJSON =<< getWith opts "http://localhost/restos-short.json" :: IO Resp
    let
        restos = jdata ^. W.responseBody
    verified <- mapM processEntry restos
    return verified

-- type StatusChecker = Status -> ResponseHeaders -> CookieJar -> Maybe SomeException
customStatusHandler :: W.StatusChecker
customStatusHandler st res _ =
    Just res
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NOTE: the answer is outdated, see other answers.**

I never used `Wreq`, but it looks like you should use `getWith` to pass custom options and [checkStatus](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.0.0/docs/Network-Wreq.html#v:checkStatus) to configure status handling.

An example:

```
getWith (set checkStatus (Just $ \_ _ _ -> Nothing) defaults)
  "http://google.com/hello/world"
```

The `\_ _ _ -> Nothing` is a function to check status code, see [StatusChecker](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.0.0/docs/Network-Wreq-Types.html#t:StatusChecker). It returns nothing indicating that any status code is OK.

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to get everything you mean here, but the problem is that Wreq is treating anything other than a `200` as an Exception, and I need to disable that

Comment: @SimonH I added an example

Comment: Thanks, and thanks also for not using the infix operators

Comment: @Yuras I think you should update or delete this answer, it is no longer correct.

Comment: I think this is a strange design decision to have exceptions by default for non-200 responses. There are many REST api's I know that respond with non-200 status codes to signal results and not necessarily to always indicate errors that need to blow up in your face. This seems like a nice library but this decision in itself makes it appear very weird to me.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on the answer by Evelyn Schneider, I got this to work with

```
r <- getWith opts url
where 
  opts = set Network.Wreq.checkResponse (Just $ \_ _ -> return ()) defaults
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (using Wreq 0.5.2.1 here)

Answer (score 5):

For posterity: newer versions of `wreq` (starting with `0.5`) have replaced `checkStatus` with `checkResponse`, which takes different arguments. An equivalent to Yuras' answer would now be:

```
getWith opts url
  where opts = set checkResponse (\_ _ -> return ()) defaults
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the `checkStatus` function I ended up with after researching a bit. I couldn't figure out how to convert a `HttpException` to a `SomeException`, but then I found `Control.Monad.Catch.SomeException`. This will ignore 404s and re-throw all other exceptions.

```
import           Network.HTTP.Client.Types
import           Network.HTTP.Types.Status
import           Network.HTTP.Types.Header
import qualified Control.Exception as E
import           Control.Monad.Catch (SomeException(..))

notFoundMeansNothing :: Status -> ResponseHeaders -> CookieJar -> Maybe E.SomeException
notFoundMeansNothing s h c
    | s == status404 = Nothing
    | otherwise =
        if statusIsClientError s || statusIsServerError s then
            Just . SomeException $ StatusCodeException s h c
        else
            Nothing
```